# What is the cloudformation type for Appsync merged API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I am looking at how Appsync merged API work in terms of subgraph federation. However, I couldn't find the cloudformation reference for merged API. The closest reference I can find is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-appsync-sourceapiassociation.html.

I wonder whether this is supported by cloudformation.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out there is a `ApiType` under `AWS::AppSync::GraphQLApi` which can be used to specify MERGED or GRAPHQL